# Trying to save a file fails with (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory) for no clear reason

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems that saving files with long names leads to problems for some reason. I won't write code here since it is hard to reproduce, but below is an image that shows this issue.

Folder structure definitely exists, you can see that for some filenames it works just fine. But then for other names without any weird special characters it fails.
[image: code snipper]

I have tried other variants like giving absolute path, but still it seems to fail. Is there maybe a fix to this, other than saving a file with a timestamp perhaps or some other kind of unique random naming?

**EDIT**
For more clarification, folder structure is the same for each of the 5 examples (everything up to the last \), I have only changed filename and for 3 examples it works fine but for other 2 it doesn't.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I guess you put TD. But this is a problem that is tedious to replicate, image is there so that it is clear that I didn't mess up anything like not changing working directory or something.

Comment: But your image is of a block of text. Why not just copy the text and paste it into your question?

Comment: Windows has filename length limits on some versions of the file systems. I'm wondering if your longest file names are too long for your filesystem,. since they are the ones failing. Are you able to manually create that path using the File Explorer? That would confirm if the filename length is the problem or not.

Comment: You should still post that code and the error message as text in the post, by the way.  This question will probably get closed shortly as it stands, mostly because of the code and error as image.

Answer (score 0):

You are using path as `DATA\\...` but path should be either `.\\DATA`: which means path from current directory or,  specify your Drive Name in starting like: `C:\\...\\DATA...`

Comment: 3/5 names are saved good, I have just changed the filename (after last \\).